# Monitoring unique clients connecting to windows server

Tags: windows

I need to see what other applications or servers are connecting to my server, and log them over time.

I only want to grab source/destination IP and ports, and use them to build a list of hosts using this server over time. I've tried a couple different tools for this:

- Netstat: If a client connection is short, netstat output doesn't catch it.
- Procmon: More resource intensive, and doesn't seem to catch incoming SMB connections (maybe I'm doing something wrong here, it catches everything else)
- Wireshark: I'm not sure what a good filter to use is. It collects so much data that it gets out of control quickly - I will need to monitor for a few weeks.

Any recommendations on a lightweight tool that will handle this?

Comment: i guess it really depends the kind of services you want to monitor. what is the server hosting ? on which ports, which protocol etc. depending on the server roles or applications, you might also have some logging already in place (as for access_log on an apache server), if it's TCP it's also easier. but you should look at the windows event log too, and your application-specific log files

Comment: It's a legacy server that is running at least print, file, and SQL servers, leading me to want to just capture all tcp/udp sessions (in addition to other investigative steps).